# Grab an html table from .gs function and call it in in .html body

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

could somebody help me to understand how can I call an HTML table generated by .gs function in the .html body dedicated to GmailApp.sendemail()?
Here is an example:

*1. First of all, we are creating an html table with data from the spreadsheet:*

```
    function createTableDHL(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("B2C DE");
  var row_count = sheet.getLastRow();  
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC", "dd/MM/yyyy"); //You can use the date format you prefer
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:D"+ (row_count + 1)).getDisplayValues(); //We get all the values from A to D and from row 2 to the last one.
  var cells = [];
  var th = [sheet.getRange("A1").getDisplayValues(), sheet.getRange("B1").getDisplayValues(), sheet.getRange("C1").getDisplayValues(), sheet.getRange("D1").getDisplayValues()];
  var table = "<table border-collapse=collapse><tr height=50 style=background-color:rgb(207,226,243)><th>" + th[0] + "</th><th width=50>" + th[1] + "</th><th width=200>" + th[2] + "</th><th>" + th[3] + "</th></tr>";

  var col_A = sheet.getRange('A2:A'+ row_count).getDisplayValues();

  for (var i = row_count; i >= 0 ; i--){

    if (col_A[i] != today){
      data.splice(i, 1);
    }

  }

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(data[i][3])))
    {
      cells = data[i].toString().split(",");
      table += "<tr>";

      for (var u = 0; u < cells.length; u++){
        table += "<td align=center>"+ cells[u] +"</td>";
      }

      table += "</tr>";
    }
  }

  table += "</table>";

  return table;

}
```

*2. The second step - passing created html table to the html message body:*
Here is the problem. The table shows up in the sent message not like a usual table, but just as a code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>

  <body>
    <p style=font-family:verdana,sans-serif > Dear All,<br><br> 
    <span style=background-color:rgb(217,234,211)><b>Delivery for today:</b></span></p>
    <?= tableDHL ?>
    <p style=font-family:verdana,sans-serif > Trucks should arrive till <b>4:30 PM</b>.<br>
    More details can be sent to you by our suppliers.<br><br>
    <span style=background-color:rgb(207,226,243)><b>Forecast:</b></span><br>
    <?= dayDelivery ?> we are planning to deliver about <b> <?= plansLow ?> - <?= plansHigh ?> parcels.</b><br><br>
    <span style=background-color:rgb(255,242,204)><b>Returns:</b></span><br>
    Tomorrow we are planning to pick up our returned packages by listed trucks:</p>
    <?= returns ?> <?= monReturns ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

*3. Here is a code which sends an email:*

```
function sendEmailsDHL(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("B2C DE");
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues(); //We get all the values from A to D and from row 2 to the last one.  

  var add1day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var add3days = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24*3;
  var today2 = new Date();
  var tomorrow = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today2.getTime() + add1day), "UTC", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  var Mon = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today2.getTime() + add3days), "UTC", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  var plansLow = 0

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

    if (Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC", "EEE") == "Fri"){

      if (data[i][0] == Mon && data[i][3] == "returns" && data[i][4] == "NL"){

        var NLmonRet = data[i][2];

      }

      if (data[i][0] == Mon && data[i][3] ==""){
        plansLow += 2000; 
      }

    }else{

      if (data[i][0] == tomorrow && data[i][3] ==""){
        plansLow += 2000; 

      }
    }
  }

  var plansHigh = Number(plansLow) + 1500;

  if (Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC", "EEE") == "Fri"){

    var dayDelivery = "On Monday";
    var MonReturns = "<br>On Monday we are planning to pick up our returned packages by listed trucks:<br>" + NLmonRet;

  }else{

    var dayDelivery = "Tomorrow";
    var MonReturns = "";

  }

  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("message");

  htmlTemplate.tableDHL = createTableDHL();
  htmlTemplate.dayDelivery = dayDelivery;
  htmlTemplate.plansLow = plansLow;
  htmlTemplate.plansHigh = plansHigh;
  htmlTemplate.returns = truckReturns();
  htmlTemplate.monReturns = MonReturns;

  var mBody = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  Logger.log(mBody)

  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    'xxxxx@gmail.com', //You can put as many emails you want
    'prealert ' + today,
    '',
    { htmlBody: mBody });
}
```

**For now, variable `<?= tableDHL ?>` in the html code looks not like a table, but only as code inside the message when I send it. How can I fix it, so it will be displayed as a table?
Thanks in advance for your help :)**

I've added logs of performed code. Here is what `Logger.log(mBody)` returns me in `mBody` message:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>

  <body>
    <p style="font-family:verdana,sans-serif" > Dear All,<br><br> 
    <span style="background-color:rgb(217,234,211)"><b>Delivery for today:</b></span></p>
    <div onLoad="this.innerHTML = '\x3ctable border-collapse=collapse\x3e\x3ctr height=50 style=background-color:rgb\(207,226,243\)\x3e\x3cth\x3eDate\x3c\/th\x3e\x3cth width=50\x3eDay\x3c\/th\x3e\x3cth width=200\x3ePlate numbers\x3c\/th\x3e\x3cth\x3eQ-ty of parcels\x3c\/th\x3e\x3c\/tr\x3e\x3ctr\x3e\x3ctd align=center\x3e14\/10\/2019\x3c\/td\x3e\x3ctd align=center\x3eMon\x3c\/td\x3e\x3ctd align=center\x3eEKURP85\/ETMWC66\x3c\/td\x3e\x3ctd align=center\x3e2 675\x3c\/td\x3e\x3c\/tr\x3e\x3ctr\x3e\x3ctd align=center\x3e14\/10\/2019\x3c\/td\x3e\x3ctd align=center\x3eMon\x3c\/td\x3e\x3ctd align=center\x3eDDZ FP20\/ DL 5334P\x3c\/td\x3e\x3ctd align=center\x3e2 298\x3c\/td\x3e\x3c\/tr\x3e\x3c\/table\x3e'"></div>
    <p style="font-family:verdana,sans-serif" > Trucks should arrive till <b>4:30 PM</b>.<br>
    More details can be sent to you by our suppliers.<br><br>
    <span style="background-color:rgb(207,226,243)"><b>Forecast:</b></span><br>
    Tomorrow we are planning to deliver about <b> 6000 - 7500 parcels.</b><br><br>
    <span style="background-color:rgb(255,242,204)"><b>Returns:</b></span><br>
    Tomorrow we are planning to pick up our returned packages by listed trucks:</p>
    &lt;table border=0&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;EKURP85/ETMWC66&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;     
  </body>
</html>
```

What is the strange symbols `td&gt;&lt` `x3c;x3e` insted of `</>`?

Comment: try `<? createTableDHL(); ?>` instead of `<?= tableDHL ?>` and remove the `htmlTemplate.tableDHL = createTableDHL();`

Answer (score 1):

try this (my first comment) :

> try `<? createTableDHL(); ?>` instead of `<?= tableDHL ?>` and remove the `htmlTemplate.tableDHL = createTableDHL();`

or

try this pattern directly in html file :

```
   <table>
      <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <tr>
          <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
            <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
```

third solution :

`<div onLoad="this.textContent = '<?= tableDHL ?>'"></div>`

Comment: Nope,
first one option doesn't work. Still getting code inside the message. Looks like:

Dear All,

Delivery for today:

<table border-collapse=collapse><tr height=50 style=background-color:rgb(207,226,243)><th>Date</th><th width=50>Day</th><th width=200>Plate numbers</th><th>Q-ty of parcels</th></tr><tr><td align=center>11/10/2019</td><td align=center>Fri</td><td align=center>EKURP85/ETMWC66</td><td align=center>2 675</td></tr><tr><td align=center>11/10/2019</td><td align=center>Fri</td><td align=center>DDZ FP20/ DL 5334P</td><td align=center>2 298</td></tr></table>

Comment: check my edit (thirs solution) and check with `.innerHTML` too

Comment: Proposed solutions don't work. I think, because of inappropriate HTML code returned by `mBody`

Comment: If you want to make to copy of you app script project and share it with me, I can take a look at it

Comment: Yeah, of course! How do you want me to send you the code? In private messaging or here?

Comment: private message and if we find out what the solution is, we'll post it here

Comment: Hey, Simon, could you tell me how to send you a private message? There is no such option in Stackoverflow. Know what? I will make a change inside the question...

Comment: oh yep sorry, contact me first on facebook --> https://www.facebook.com/simon.dehaut